# Is there a way to render out an animation from the 3D view?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

Is there a way to render a sequence of frames from the "3D view" (not the final render, but in solid mode, for example), except the screen capture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Click the movie icon beneath the 3D View

[image]

- Here is the menu venue

[image]

Comment: Pazhalasta Konechna

Comment: That's a fancy indicator arrow you got there...